# How to enable Geolocation Based Statistics in WSO2 IS Analytics 5.8.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We found an error 'N/A' in column region after enable Geolocation Based Statistics
[image]

I have done the steps as follows

> 1. Download the geolocation data
> 2. Create the database by executing one of the scripts in the Geolocation Data/dbscripts, I use the mysql database
> 3. Populate the data to the BLOCKS and LOCATION tables in the database geo_location_data, from the following files Geolocation
>      Data/data/BLOCKS.csv Geolocation Data/data/LOCATION.csv
> 4. Download a JDBC provider for MySQL and Copy the mysql-connector-java.jar to /lib directory
> 5. Configure the following in /conf/worker/deployment.yaml file as given below
>      [image]
> 6. Configure the following in /wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files/IS_ANALYTICS_AUTHENTICATION_COMMON.sidddhi
>      file as given below [image]
> 7. Restart WSO2 IS & WSO2 IS Analytics.

any advice? so that region column can show real location when user access the application

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above steps, you need to have the proper IPs in order to get it working. It derives the region based on the user IPs. Then you should be able to see the relevant stats as below,

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi ashensw, the following link what needs to be fixed? https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/enabling-geolocation-based-statistics/
because there is no data in the ip_location table.
I hope you can help to find a solution

Comment: Hi @IhsanJazuli, What I meant was if an actual person logs in from another country, actual IP will be sent with the authentication data stream to the IS analytics. But if you are trying it locally it won't work. As a workaround, you can try to use the is-analytics-client mentioned in the above documentation. It will generate some dummy data with actual IPs and publish to the IS analytics. So then you should be able to see the regions for those data.

Comment: Hi Ashensw nice info, if i dont configure "Enabling Geolocation Based Statistics" in the above documentation. whether wso2is analytics can show IP or Region user trying to access from outside country?

Comment: Then it will show only the IPs. But you have to enable the 'Geolocation Based Statistics' in order to populate the above map and also to see the region in the data table.

Comment: i see. i have location and blocks table in database geo_location_data from the above documentation. for example,  i want to see IP 152.101.145.121 from the table location and blocks, can you show me the sql query how to get the hongkong region based on ip 152.101.145.121? because I'm confused with the values in the network_cidr, network, broadcast columns. thanks a lot Ashensw

Comment: Well, it's not using direct SQL language. IS analytics using a complex event processing language called siddhi [https://siddhi.io/en/v4.x/docs/] to process these events. So when you are enabling the geolocation you have uncommented the line with siddhi function "geo:findCountryFromIP(remoteIp)" [https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-geo/] which is used to get the country from the IP. So if you have the requirement you can enable this feature. Then it will give the relevant region information in the dashboard when the authentication events come with proper IP ranges.